# R commandArgs() suppress warnings about arguments being ignored

Tags: r

On Windows 10 for the script xcommandargs.r,

```
options(warn=-1)
sink("NUL")
x <- suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(commandArgs()))
sink()
print(x)
```

running the command

```
C:\programs\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\rterm.exe --vanilla --slave < xcommandargs.r foo bar
```

gives output

```
ARGUMENT 'foo' __ignored__

ARGUMENT 'bar' __ignored__

[1] "C:\\programs\\R\\R-3.6.1\\bin\\x64\\rterm.exe"
[2] "--vanilla"                                    
[3] "--slave"                                      
[4] "foo"                                          
[5] "bar"
```

How can I suppress the warnings about arguments being ignored? My attempts in the code to suppress the warnings did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sending standing error to nul via

```
C:\programs\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\rterm.exe --vanilla --slave < xcommandargs.r foo bar 2> nul
```

suppresses the "ARGUMENT ... ignored" messages.